# Pros and cons of having CSS as part of a theme

Tags: asp.net, themes, skin

What are some pros/cons in using CSS as part of a theme instead of manually supplying `<link>` tag in the `<head>` section of a web page?

Comment: Wha? You may want to re-word this. It's awfully confusing. Are you talking about embedding CSS vs. Linking to external CSS?

Comment: I’m asking whether we should put external CSS ( that’s why I mentioned <link> tag ) into a theme or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ASP.NET, using a **theme** makes it easier to integrate your CSS styles with the Localization, Accessibility, and Navigation features of that development platform.

Using your own manual CSS file (referenced from the HTML with a `<style>` or `<link>` tag) means that you have to maintain the file yourself, potentially including any browser-specific CSS code. However, going this route will probably afford you a higher degree of portability if, for instance, you decided to switch to another platform (eg. LAMP).

Comment: “In ASP.NET, using a theme makes it easier to integrate your CSS styles with the Localization, Accessibility, and Navigation features of that development platform.” May I ask how CSS being a part of a theme makes it easier to integrate CSS styles with Localization…?

Comment: Simply by indirection. If you use a theme per language (or target "culture") and the theme includes the CSS, then changing the theme (language) dynamically also changes the CSS. You don't have to generate the `<link>` tags dynamically or anything.